# 1 div, 1 text input, side by side, stretch input to 100% with no fixed width on either

Tags: html, css

I've got 2 elements, a div and a text input side by side.
The widths of neither is unknown and I'm trying to get the text input to fill the remaining width of the container.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#url {
  margin: 6px 2px 0 0;
  float: left;
}

#input_1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="url">http://example.com/images/</div>
  <input id="input_1" name="input_1" type="text" value="somefile.jpg" />
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5udnbz3/)

Any suggestions?

***EDIT**

Here's a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5f3aegjb/) using Nick's answer in case anybody else needs it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this? If so, flexbox is your friend, my friend.

```css
.wrap {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#url {
  margin: 6px 2px 0 0;
  width: auto;
}
#input_1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="url">http://example.com/images/</div>
  <input id="input_1" name="input_1" type="text" value="somefile.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it's wrapping the div over two lines. I need it to stay on a single line.

Comment: hm, are you sure you're referencing this exactly? in any modernish browser this should be single line.

Comment: @spice gotcha. just updated the css for #url. try it now?

Comment: Thanks Nick but it's still doing it. Just checked on Chrome and it's perfect. Firefox isn't feeling it though.. Weird.

Comment: FYI works fine on Brave too. Maybe my FF just needs a reboot?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `flex`

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#url {
  margin: 6px 2px 0 0;
}

#input_1 {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="url">http://example.com/images/</div>
  <input id="input_1" name="input_1" type="text" value="somefile.jpg" />
</div>
```

Solution without flex

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#left {
  margin: 6px 2px 0 0;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#input {
  width: 98%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="left">http://example.com/images/</div>
  <div id="right">
    <input id="input" name="input_1" type="text" value="somefile.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is flex fully supported in all main browsers? Is there a non-flex solution or is this my only hope obi-wan?

Comment: @spice I've provided solution without flex

Comment: Thanks my friend. I'm going to go with the other answer as Nick was first, but I really appreciate you taking the time to show this in both flex and non-flex versions.

Comment: @spice sure :) glad that I've helped!